# Transfer data between two database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Goal:
Database SQL server should transfer data from a table to database MySQL in every month.

Problem:
What option do you recommend me to use?

Comment: Are these servers located on the same network?

Comment: Yes.

The databases are located in the same client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with SSIS:

[MySQL Data Transfer using Sql Server Integration Services (SSIS)](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-data-transfer-using-sql-server-integration-services-ssis)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of answers for SSIS, which is an excellent product. If you have the service installed as part of your SQL Server installation then I'd recommend it. If you do not have the feature available to you (e.g. you're running Express, Workgroup, or Web editions), then I'd recommend the Pentaho suite (Kettle, specifically). It is open source.

If you have SQL Server Standard or above, then look into using SSIS. You will need to install the MySQL Connector and set it as your destination (which will become clear once you've successfully installed the tools).

You will need to install the SSIS Service somewhere. Depending on how much processing, and data volumes, this may need to be on a separate server.

You will also need to install the tools. On SQL Server version 2005-2008R2 this is called "Business Intelligence Development Studio" which is basically a VS shell with BI-specific components.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server Integration Services.

Comment: Is there a open source version?